# Why is .join returning [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, join, position

Why is `var test = positions.join("/");`  returning [object Object]/[object Object]/[object Object] and so on?
what needs to be changed in-order for this to work properly?

It should be returning positions like 0,0/0,360/0,660. Im not sure if the commas would be in there though.

```
$(function() {
    $('.AppList').droppable({
        accept: ".App",
        tolerance: 'fit',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var apps = $(".App"),
            positions = [];

            $.each(apps, function (index, app) {
                var positionInfo = $(app).position();

                positions.push(positionInfo);
            });
            var test = positions.join("/");
            console.log(test);
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: What is returns by function position()? An object, right?

Comment: Because $(app).position() is returning an object like { top: 10, left: 10}

Comment: okay so how to i get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
var test = JSON.stringify(positions);
console.log(test);
```

No need to invent your own serialization format.

Comment: How would i now split this back into an array?

Comment: @ChristopherStrydom: try `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 1):

You are returning object from function position(). Try this instead:

```
 $.each(apps, function (index, app) {
           var pos =  $(app).position(),   
               positionInfo = pos.top+","+ pos.left;

            positions.push(positionInfo);
        });
```

Comment: this is now returning [undefined Undefined]?

Comment: Use console.log($(app).position()) to see how looks your object, it seems not to be .X & .Y, maybe .top & .left

Comment: okay it now looks like this Object { top=60, left=0 }

Comment: i need to use this `$.each(apps, function (index, app) {` because i have multiple divs and i want to get the positions of all of them. Here is a question i asked earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245137/array-slice-returning-object-object-instead-of-value

Comment: @ChristopherStrydom - Isn't that the very same problem, except with a different object. The solution is exactly the same.

Comment: yea it is but i cant seem to find the solution even though you say its the same i don't know what syntax i need to use to make it work as before.

Answer (score 0):

The [Array.join() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) returns a string. Since your array items are [objects](http://api.jquery.com/position/) you can't expect anything particularly useful—`[object Object]` is what JavaScript creates as default when casting objects to strings.